# Filtering a data set by a vector including repeated elements

Tags: r, filter, subset

Mandatory "Sorry for the opaque title" message.

I have a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame( l = rep(letters[1:3], each=3) , 
                  n = rep(1:3, 3)
                 )
```

I would like to subset the data by the grouping variable `l` from a separate vector, such as:

```
df[df$l %in% c("a","b"),]
```

This works, but now imagine I want to subset using the vector `c("a","b","a","a","c","c")`. When I try this with R's `%in%` operator, it only returns the rows with the unique elements of the vector:

```
df[df$l %in% c("a","b","a","a","c","c"),]

  l n
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 a 3
4 b 1
5 b 2
6 b 3
7 c 1
8 c 2
9 c 3
```

Is there an alternative to `%in%` to filter a `data.frame` by a grouping variable using a vector with repeated elements?

EDIT: to be clear, in the second case above I want to get:

```
  l n
1 a 1
2 a 2
3 a 3
4 b 1
5 b 2
6 b 3
7 a 1
8 a 2
9 a 3 
10 a 1
11 a 2 
12 a 3
13 c 1
14 c 2
15 c 3
16 c 1 
17 c 2
18 c 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(l = rep(letters[1:3], each=3), n = rep(1:3, 3))

do.call(rbind, lapply(c("a","b","a","a","c","c"), function(x) df[df$l %in% x, ]))

   l n
1  a 1
2  a 2
3  a 3
4  b 1
5  b 2
6  b 3
11 a 1
21 a 2
31 a 3
12 a 1
22 a 2
32 a 3
7  c 1
8  c 2
9  c 3
71 c 1
81 c 2
91 c 3
```

***Edit:*** If ordered number of rows are important:

```
rownames(df_new) <- NULL
```

, then row names of the new saved df will be from 1:18 .

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way, but I think this produces the correct result.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(c("a","b","a","a","c","c"), function(x) df %>% filter(l == x)))
```

This goes through your vector of letters and filters for each, then binds the resulting list into a data frame. It requires `dplyr` for `%>%` and `filter`.

```
#    l n
# 1  a 1
# 2  a 2
# 3  a 3
# 4  b 1
# 5  b 2
# 6  b 3
# 7  a 1
# 8  a 2
# 9  a 3
# 10 a 1
# 11 a 2
# 12 a 3
# 13 c 1
# 14 c 2
# 15 c 3
# 16 c 1
# 17 c 2
# 18 c 3
```

---

To make it a bit easier to use, you could define an operator:

```
"%filter%" <- function(df, search_list){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(search_list, function(x) df %>% filter(l == x)))
}

MyVec <- c("a","b","a","a","c","c")

df %filter% MyVec

#    l n
# 1  a 1
# 2  a 2
# 3  a 3
# 4  b 1
# 5  b 2
# 6  b 3
# 7  a 1
# 8  a 2
# 9  a 3
# 10 a 1
# 11 a 2
# 12 a 3
# 13 c 1
# 14 c 2
# 15 c 3
# 16 c 1
# 17 c 2
# 18 c 3
```

---

On second thoughts, the operator is pretty stupid as it only works for columns called `l`. This function is a bit more generic.

```
MyFilter <- function(df, search_list, column_name){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(search_list, function(x) df %>% filter(get(column_name) == x)))
}

MyFilter(df, MyVec, "l")

#    l n
# 1  a 1
# 2  a 2
# 3  a 3
# 4  b 1
# 5  b 2
# 6  b 3
# 7  a 1
# 8  a 2
# 9  a 3
# 10 a 1
# 11 a 2
# 12 a 3
# 13 c 1
# 14 c 2
# 15 c 3
# 16 c 1
# 17 c 2
# 18 c 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `dplyr::inner_join` can do the trick.

```
data.frame(l = c("a","b","a","a","c","c")) %>% inner_join(df,by = 'l')
```